# keras/tensorflow does not find weights file imagenet

Tags: tensorflow, keras, imagenet

The following minimal example code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tensorflow.contrib.keras.api import keras
model = keras.applications.xception.Xception(input_shape=(299, 299, 3))
```

fails with

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/applications/xception.py", line 307, in Xception
    model.load_weights(weights)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1101, in load_weights
    f = h5py.File(filepath, mode='r')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 269, in __init__
    fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, swmr=swmr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 99, in make_fid
    fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 78, in h5py.h5f.open
OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'imagenet', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```

even when doing this before running:

```
rm -r ~/.keras/models/
```

Then it successfully downloads `https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.4/xception_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5` again, but comes up with the same error afterwards. What am I missing?

I'm using TensorFlow version 1.5.0 (tensorflow-gpu from `pip3`) on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: try pip install -U h5py

Comment: @Paddy h5py is already installed, that's not the problem.

Comment: yep, but I suggested update the h5py

Comment: Seems that it's an issue specific to TF-Keras. It's discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16683#issuecomment-363621409) and has been fixed.

Comment: @Yu-Yang: Thanks, this is the solution. Would you like to post it as an answer?

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue specific to TF-Keras. It's discussed in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16683#issuecomment-363621409) and has been fixed. According to the author,

> It was introduced in PR [#15146](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/15146) and it applies to both Xception and
>   MobileNet.
>
> However, it has been fixed since. If you upgrade to TF 1.6, you will
>   no longer see this issue. For instance, you can `pip install` the TF 1.6
>   release candidate `1.6.0rc0` as of now.